iMac can‘t boot OS X, neither install Ubuntu from Bootstick
I bought an old iMac from 2010 off eBay in Germany as broken and thought about restoring it.
After a Bit of troubleshooting I found out that it wasn‘t a Hardware Problem.
I found grub as I started the iMac with the SSD that came pre build with it. I can‘t Access any recovery Mode or disk utility Mode from Apple, just the alt/option button thing works to select the harddrive which is named (EFI or EFI BOOT) or something Like that.
I thought about installing Ubuntu from a bootstick but while installing I Receive a install failure, so I can only try Ubuntu from my bootstick.
Is there anything that I can do to completely wipe grub form my harddrive and somehow restore the Apple Original Stuff?
I also can‘t install nor boot with a bootstick with Mac OS on it (Snowfall Lion or how this was called).
While booting the bootstick the Apple Logo is showing up, the Keyboard shuts down and it seems Like it freezes. Also with a external harddrive it is Not working.

The way your question reads, you’re asking about how to reinstall Apple osx on the device - you won’t get help for that here. Might be better to limit the question (on this site) to ‘how can I install Ubuntu on this Mac?’

Boot your Apple install media and install it; it'll automatically remove the bootloader which from your description is the GNU Bootloader (GRUB). You don't use an unwanted OS to remove grub; you use the OS you want to keep/have take ownership of boot which will overwrite grub.

FYI:   If you're trying to boot external media of any type (eg. Apple) and you're seeing the installed bootloader; either your boot media is invalid (thus is being ignored by your Apple firmware) OR you're not following the procedures as set out for your brand/model product (ie. Apple xyz device), and the problem is not GRUB, but grub appearing is a symptom showing a machine or procedural (you) error...    If grub is removed, the problem will still exist, but you'll just get a black screen (or however your machine firmware is coded to deal with that error)

If you can boot from a bootable Ubuntu live USB to an Ubuntu live session, then you can launch the built-in GParted partition editor and format the iMac's entire hard drive to FAT32 format. Then you will be able to boot from the USB stick with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard on it, and install macOS on your iMac. Alternatively the cause of the problem may be program that you used to create the USB stick with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard on it, so please comment and tell me the name of this program.
